# picture in caption leads to error in main listing of figures

Tags: captions

Using

```
    \caption{Some text \protect\includegraphics[height=.3cm]{figure.jpg} again some text.}
```

leads to a perfect list of figures of that chapter:

[image]

but errors in the main list of figures:

[image]

What to do? Thanks a lot,
Harry

Comment: The information you've given is insufficient to diagnose this problem.  Please add a small compilable example that demonstrates this result.  The example should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, and contain only what's necessary to replicate the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP, in a self-answer, said it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

@barbara beeton: thanks for your comment:

Meanwhile I was able to fix this error: setting the graphicspath for all figures used in the paper works fine, but seems to be ignored by the main listing. So I copied the jpg's also in the main directory of the tex-files, and now it works.